# Compare Array in an array(as its value) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I got 2 ass-array like below

First:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'ma_ncc' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'ma_ncc' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'ma_ncc' => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'ma_ncc' => string '4' (length=1)
```

Second:

```
 array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'ma_ncc' => string '999' (length=3)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'ma_ncc' => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'ma_ncc' => string '1' (length=1)
```

How can I compare those array (Arrays as value)

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Please tell what is desired output? Any example?

Comment: I expect an output array like array('ma_ncc'=>999) that indicate the value '999' is not in the first-array

Comment: I've tried. "array_diff", "array_diff_assoc" as well. But it did return the result that I expect it to be!

Comment: @Rizier123 I know and I'm sorry. But I just hope for an idea. I don't looking for someone write full code for me!

Answer (score 0):

**Use array_diff() function.**

```
Example: 
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: array_diff is not working well in this case. I just was wondering, is there any available method to compare this kind of array. So finally. I have to convert 2 assoc-arrays into 2 array by foreach method then compare it with array_diff. But thank anyway

Answer (score 0):

Please try array_diff_assoc function

```
<?php
          $array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
          $array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
          $result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
           print_r($result);

?>
```